# RISC-V PMP Address Configuration

Tags: specifications, riscv, instruction-set

I am currently learning about PMP in RISC-V, I understand about the TOR, but I'm getting difficulties to understand NA4 and NAPOT configuration

[image]

Can someone make an explanation ? My assumption is, if my `pmpaddr` is `0xFFFFFFFE` then it means my pmp ranges from `0xFFFFFFFE00` to `0xFFFFFFFEFF`. Is this right?

Answer (score 4):

I can give you the answrer.
if pmpaddr is `0xFFFFFFFE`, (1111....1110), it will matches address from `1111....111000` to `1111...111111`(8 bytes).
The length of pmpaddr is 32 bits, and the length of memory is 34 bits.
You can understand this with subnet mask of IP addr.
This means the last zero is the indicator bit, the high bits must all match.